# How to initialize a convolution layer with an arbitrary kernel in Keras?

Tags: initialization, neural-network, keras, convolution, keras-layer

I want to initialize the convolution layer by a specific kernel which is not defined in Keras. For instance, if I define the below function to initialize the kernel:

```
def init_f(shape):
      ker=np.zeros((shape,shape))
      ker[int(np.floor(shape/2)),int(np.floor(shape/2))]=1
      return ker
```

And the convolution layer is designed as follows:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),
                      kernel_initializer=init_f(3)))
```

I get the error:

> Could not interpret initializer identifier

I have followed a similar issue at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/J46pplO64-8
But I could not adapt it to my code.
Could you please help me to define the arbitrary kernel in Keras?

Answer (score 9):

A few items to fix. Let's start with the kernel initializer. From [the documentation](https://keras.io/initializers/#using-custom-initializers):

> If passing a custom callable, then it must take the argument shape (shape of the variable to initialize) and dtype (dtype of generated values)

So the signature should become:

```
def init_f(shape, dtype=None)
```

The function will work without the `dtype`, but it's good practice to keep it there. That way you can specify the `dtype` to calls inside your function, e.g.:

```
np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
```

This also addresses your second issue: the `shape` argument is a tuple, so you just need to pass it straight to `np.zeros` and don't need to make another tuple.

I'm guessing you're trying to initialize the kernel with a 1 in the middle, so you could also generalize your function to work with whatever shape it receives:

```
ker[tuple(map(lambda x: int(np.floor(x/2)), ker.shape))]=1
```

Putting it all together:

```
def init_f(shape, dtype=None):
    ker = np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    ker[tuple(map(lambda x: int(np.floor(x/2)), ker.shape))]=1
    return ker
```

One last problem. You need to pass *the function* to the layer, not the result of the call:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),
                  kernel_initializer=init_f))
```

The layer function will pass the arguments to `init_f`.